# Integrating infinitesimal discs to find the volume of a sphere

Tags: integration

Let's assume I have a sphere of Radius 'R'.

I am trying to prove that its volume is equal to
$\frac{4}{3}\pi R^{3}$ using a disc as an element

[image]

The radius of this element is $R\sin\theta$, and the arc length is $Rd\theta$

I write the small volume of this element as $dV=\pi\left(R\sin\theta\right)^{2}\cdot Rd\theta$

And to get the total volume, I integrate all such elements (from 0 to $\pi$)

this gives me $\int_{0}^{\pi}\pi\left(R\sin\theta\right)^{2}\cdot Rd\theta$

which is $\frac{\pi^{2}R^{3}}{2}$.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Hint: the thickness is parallel to the $\theta=0$ radius, so is actually $R|\cos\theta|d\theta$. Compare [this](https://youtu.be/VYQVlVoWoPY).

Comment: If you're using cylindrical discs, then you should not be using the element of arc-length, as you call it, but rather its projection in the direction of the axis of the disc.

Answer (score 1):

When $\vartheta=0$ or $\pi$ your small integration element is parallel to the circular discs, and the volume element vanishes.

If you do the integral with $\pi y^2 \, \mathrm d x = \pi \left ( R \sin \vartheta \right )^2 \left ( R \sin \vartheta \, \mathrm d \vartheta \right )$ with $x=-R\cos\vartheta$ you will get the correct answer. This is actually one of those little things that motivates the study of differential forms and Jacobians.

Comment: If I tried finding the surface area in a similar way, but instead using dA=2π(Rsinθ)∗Rsinθdθ
 would it still be right?

Comment: No, it will be wrong. Instead, it should be $\mathrm d A = 2 \pi y \sqrt{ \left ( \frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d \vartheta} \right )^2 + \left ( \frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d \vartheta} \right )^2 } \mathrm d \vartheta = 2 \pi ( R \sin \vartheta ) ( R \, \mathrm d \vartheta ) $

Comment: Can you explain why we take this?

Comment: The surface area form needs to capture the arclength part correctly, or else it would be too much of an underestimate. In general, if you want to find an integral correctly, the integral must take all the first order behaviour fully into account. It can be wrong in the second order, because that will be irrelevant in the limit. But it must be careful with the first order behaviours. $2\pi y \, \mathrm d x$ is just wrong enough to be really wrong.